# How to set the row size in vaardin-grid v2.0 polymer element?

Tags: vaadin-grid

How do I set the row size in vaardin-grid v2.0 polymer element? Is it possible to auto set the row size to fit the size of the items automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the row to be dynamic by setting the 'items' property of the vaadin-grid element.

```
<vaadin-grid
            id="grid"
            aria-label="Remote Data Example"
            items="[[data]]"
            loading="{{loading}}"
            style="height: auto;"
            active-item="{{activeItem}}">
        <!--<vaadin-grid-selection-column auto-select></vaadin-grid-selection-column>-->
        <vaadin-grid-column width="50px" flex-grow="0">
            <template class="header">#</template>
            <template>[[index]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Process</template>
            <template>[[item.name]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Start Time</template>
            <template>[[item.startTime]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Owner</template>
            <template>[[item.group]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Reactor</template>
            <template>[[item.reactor]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Host Name</template>
            <template>[[item.hostName]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

    </vaadin-grid>
```

you can set the 'data' which is your payload from a response from an iron-ajax element.

Comment: You can set also a fixed size with the property 'size' on vaadin-grid

Comment: I guess the answer that I am looking for is to set `style="height: auto;"` at `<vaadin-grid>`, it is set at `400px` by default. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, that will set the grid to be as high as the rows ;) Please accept this as the answer if it answers your question :)